# Create a straight line with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, uitouch

How can I create a straight line using SpriteKit and `UITouch`?

I wanted a method that allowed me to add the start point and the end point instead of a path. Just like a rubber band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Create** a `SKShapeNode` that is a line when user begins the touch movement e.g. in `touchesBegan:`.

   ```
   SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];
   CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(..., ...)
   CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(..., ...)

   CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
   CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
   CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

   line.path = pathToDraw;
   line.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor]];
   [self addChild:line];
   ```
2. **Modify** its path to change its length in `touchesMoved:`